# Font smoothing in the Terminal

Tags: linux, fedora, fonts

I've noticed that the fonts that the default font on emacs is a lot smoother and easier on the eye than the font inside the terminal.

Although they are both supposedly monospace 12 fonts, I was wondering if could somehow make the terminal font similar to the one used by emacs by default.

---

Details:

- using gnome-terminal with bash
- Fedora 18 with Gnome3

Emacs:
[image]

Terminal:
[image]

Screen shots from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84623/terminal-font-is-not-smooth 
May give you a better idea of what I'm saying. Only I'm not on a Mac.

Comment: Screenshots or it didn't happen.

Comment: Haha, Added as per request. Not sure if it's as visible here as it is on my screen though. :P